# Cloud Run Caching old revisions

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, redux, google-cloud-run

After deploying a new revision of our code to our cloud run instance, some users are still working on the older revision. This happens even if the user closes their window and reopens or refreshes their page. The cloud run instance is runinng Javascript React Redux code. Does anyone know of any reasons why this could be happening? We have the cloud run instance set to serve 100% of traffic to the most recent healthy revision.

I tried toggling the "serve 100% of traffic to the most recent health revision" off and then on again and I viewed the traffic flow percentage to make sure it was set to 100% most recent revision.

Comment: This might be because of the following reasons: browser cache, cdn cache (if you are using a content delivery network), load balancing, and dns cache. You can also check logs from your cloud run instance if there are any error messages that could clarify on the issue.

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya Thank you for the suggestions. I beleive you are right and it is Browser Cache. I guess now we have to implement a way to prompt users to refresh whenever we release. There  are no errors in the log (thankfully). Anyways thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer to help other community member if they encounter the same issue with you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the following reasons: browser cache, cdn cache (if you are using a content delivery network), load balancing, and dns cache. You can also check logs from your cloud run instance if there are any error messages that could clarify on the issue.